# Maintain element centered vertically and horizontally of a image in any width device

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an image div with a element inside that i want to be positionated on center (vertical and horizontal) when user hover the box. I can do it (the hover effect and appear the icon hover the image), but i can't centered the icon (a plus icon), in the center of the image, vertically and horizontally. I tried to use percents and position absolute but it's not a solution because i need to insert a lot of sentences in each media queries to establish a new top and left position depending the resolution. How can i do it "automatic"? I see topics related in stackoverflow but it's not like my problem, because my image is an element block, not a background, so i can't do background-center. I Made a JSFiddle, look the icon plus, i want to be centered in the image in any width device: http://jsfiddle.net/nj44cv5q/1/

HTML CODE:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-12 -col-sm-12 box-news">   
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-12 -col-sm-12">
            <p class="fecha-noticia-multi hidden-md hidden-lg">
            <img src="images/calendar-white.png"  class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image 10" />
            2 de Febrero de 2015
            </p>
         <a href="#" class="darken">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-260-193-10.jpg" class="img-responsive b1" alt="B1 image">
                  <div class="overlay">
                            <div class="more">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign plus-box" aria-hidden="true">
                                </span>
                            </div>
                  </div>
        </a>
    </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-12 -col-sm-12">
                    <div class="noticia-info">
                        <h2>Iberdrola vende por 192 millones las brasileñas Coelba y Cosern.</h2>
                    <div><p  class="desc2">La operación reporta plusvalías de 69 millones a la eléctrica, que ha cumplido ya el 95% de su plan de desinversiones.</p>
                                    <p class="fecha-noticia-multi hidden-xs hidden-sm"><img src="images/calendar-white.png"  class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image 10" />2 de Febrero de 2015</p>
                    </div>
                 </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
        <span class="slider-bottom-wide"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 hidden-md hidden-lg">
        <span class="slider-bottom-wide-max"></span>
        </div>
 </div>
```

CSS CODE:

```
.box-news:hover img.b1 {
 opacity: 0.7;
}
.box-news div.overlay {
    position:relative;
    top:10em;
    left: 44%;
    vertical-align:middle;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.box-news:hover {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.box-news:hover .overlay {
    opacity:1;
     top: -8em;
     left: 44%;
}



.darken:hover img {
    opacity: 0.7;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

a.darken {
    display: block;
    background: black;
    padding: 0;
    overflow:hidden;

}
.box div.overlay {
    position:relative;
    top:10em;
    left: 44%;
    vertical-align:middle;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.box:hover {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.darken:hover .overlay {
    opacity:1;
     top: -8em;
     left: 44%;
}

.plus-box {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    position: absolute;

}
```

Comment: TL;DR. But you have an extra hyphen here: `-col-sm-12` on your the `2`nd line. And also in the `div` parent of `.noticia-info`.

Comment: Thanks guys but this not solve the problem...

Comment: That's why I haven't posted this as an answer to your question :)

Comment: Sorry, i changed all the hyphens but the plus icon is showing in the bottom of the image when i'm in 768x width device for example..